# Retrieving Data From Firebase Auto Id's - Firebase Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to capture all the values in my childByAutoId in firebase. Essentially, it stores all the items that a person has shortlisted. However, I do not seem to be capturing this, and I assume it is because I am not calling the snapshot correctly to factor the auto id's.

Database:

```
userID
 -> Favourited
    -> Auto Id
      -> itemName: x
    -> Auto Id
      -> itemName: x
    -> Auto Id
      -> itemName: x
```

Code:

```
func retrieveItems() {
        
  guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

  let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userId)/Favourited")
        
   ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
       self.favUsers.removeAll()
       for likes in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
       let likesObject = likes.value as? [String: AnyObject]
       let itemName = likesObject!["itemName"]
       let likesList = Names(id: likes.key, itemName: itemName as! String?)
       self.favUsers.append(likesList)
  }
  } else {
    print("not yet")
  }
  })
    self.favList.reloadData()
  }
```

Could someone have a look and let me know what I may be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because Firebase loads data asynchronously, and right now you're calling `reloadData` before the `self.favUsers.append(likesList)` has ever run.

The call to `reloadData` needs to be inside the close/completion handler that is called when the data comes back from Firebase:

```
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
     self.favUsers.removeAll()
     for likes in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
       let likesObject = likes.value as? [String: AnyObject]
       let itemName = likesObject!["itemName"]
       let likesList = Names(id: likes.key, itemName: itemName as! String?)
       self.favUsers.append(likesList)
    }
    self.favList.reloadData() //  Move this here
  } else {
    print("not yet")
  }
})
```

I also recommend checking out some of these answers [asynchronous data loading in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+asynchronous).

Comment: Ah wow,  I can't believe I missed out on that! Thank you so much for the explanation and link!