# Check If Child Value Exists Multiple Times - Firebase and Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently learning extensively about Firebase and Swift. I came across a question / wondered if this is possible. As you can see below, this is my current database.

Is it possible to check whether itemName contains the same value, for example 'Milk' on multiple days? Currently, this is my code below however 1 big error is that it only checks whether the Parent node exists and if so, execute the statement. Is there a way to check for example, if an itemName has been added twice or more times on different days, then execute the statement? If someone could share their thoughts with me, I would really appreciate it! Thanks so much.

Edit To Help Understand Better:
Essentially, compare if itemName value exists in 2 or more children (the dates). I understand how to grab the screenshot of the entire database or specific child and values I need but I am not sure on how to check if the value for itemName exists multiple times.

Firebase Database

```
-> users
   -> User ID
      -> Items
         -> Sunday, Oct 10, 2021
            -> ChildbyAutoId
                -> itemName: Milk
         -> Monday, Oct 11, 2021
            -> ChildbyAutoId
                -> itemName: Bread
         -> Tuesday, Oct 12, 2021
            -> ChildbyAutoId
               -> itemName: Milk
```

Code Only To Check If 'Parent' Exists

```
guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

let mainRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userId)")
    mainRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshots in
     if snapshots.hasChild("Items") {
         print("exists") 
     } else {
         print("does not exist")
     }
```

Attempt to compare values of all 'itemNames' and compare if they exist in multitudes

```
 guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

 Database.database().reference().child("users/\(userId)/Items").child("itemName").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

let userDict = snapshot.value as Any as? String ?? "" // trying to obtain all values in Items which have a child named itemName. My aim is to print these out such as Milk, Bread, Eggs for now. Then eventually, append them in an array and compare if they exist in different dates. Is this the right approach?

   print(userDict)
            
})
```

Comment: I already showed you how to loop over the child snapshots in answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69497081 That should allow you to loop over the dates and childByAutoId child snapshots. Did you try that?

Comment: I have updated the question above. What I am trying to do (which I am not sure if it is the right approach) but obtaining a snapshot of all values that have a child 'itemName'. I wanted to do this and then compare if they exist in multiple childs. If you could have a look please! I don't seem to be obtaining the right snapshot though which I assume is because I am not factoring in the dates & the auto ids?

Comment: In my previous answer I showed how to loop over the children of the snapshot inside your callback. You'll need the same here, loop over all dates first, similar to how we looped over `snapshot.children.allObjects` in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69497081/209103). Then you can do the same to loop over the auto IDs in that loop (so nesting two loops), and finally get the value of `itemName` in there. Unless you can show us what you already tried, the answer is going to be pretty much the same as yesterday.